# Collapse entire bootstrap accordion with Jinja2 template variables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 variable (list of tuples). It's called `BKeys`. And I am making a bootstrap accordion for each of those tuples. However, I want each panel in the accordion to be, by default, collapsed.

The accordion is being populated correctly, but each of the panels are all open when the page loads, despite my attempt at JQuery to close them.

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  {% for bkey in BKeys %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" id="Bheader{{ bkey[1] }}" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Bcollapse{{ bkey[1] }}">{{ bkey[0] }}</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="Bcollapse{{ bkey[1] }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body" id="Bbody{{ bkey [1] }}">
          Test1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
  {% for bkey in BKeys %}
    //Hides all accordion objects when the page loads
    $("#Bcollapse{{ bkey[1] }}").collapse("hide");
  {% endfor %}
</script>
```

Also, it would be optimal if whenever a new panel is opened, all of the others shut. But the main issue here is getting them all to close immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the `in` class in your code. Bootstrap collapsible elements are collapsed by default.

The accordion behavior you describe is also there by default if you're using proper markup.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse